# Exception when apns token based trust in a production environment (windows server 2012r2)

Tags: c#, ios, apple-push-notifications

I use [httptwo](https://github.com/Redth/HttpTwo) for apns token based trust. And it works fine in my dev enviorment(which is windows 10 pro, vs 2015). I can push my notice and my device can receive it.
When I deploy the same code on the production env(aws server, windows server 2012r2), I got an exception when I send a push notice to apple.(Exeception below)

I also imported geotrust_global_ca to the server as apple said and not help. Any idea where went wrong? I guess it's some authorize problem but have no clue what it is. And I didn't do any special operation when I was coding as I remembered.

Thanks.

---

System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The message received was unexpected or badly formatted
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at HttpTwo.Http2Connection.d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at HttpTwo.Http2Client.d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at HttpTwo.Http2Client.d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at HttpTwo.Http2MessageHandler.d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at BTDDBServer.PushNotice.IOSNoticePusher.<Link>d__11.MoveNext() in D:\vsprojects\BeTheDealerServer\BTDDBServer\PushNotice\IOSNoticePusher.cs:line 182
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at BTDDBServer.PushNotice.IOSNoticePusher.d__9.MoveNext() in D:\vsprojects\BeTheDealerServer\BTDDBServer\PushNotice\IOSNoticePusher.cs:line 135

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer finally, windows server 2012r2 doesn't support http2 protocol, has to change to windows server 2016